# About directionality in a topological graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, graph-traversal

I am solving [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/course-schedule/) question on LeetCode.com.  A statement in the question says:

> Some courses may have prerequisites, for example to take course 0 you have to first take course 1, which is expressed as a pair: [0,1]

My aim is to come up with a graphical representation.  My question is, as per the above statement, should I create a graph from:

a. `0 -> 1`; or 
b. `1 -> 0`?

The reason I am confused is, if I come up with the former, I would actually do the *opposite* of what is required - I would visit `0` before I do the prerequisite `1`.  On the other hand, if I do it the latter way, what if there's a scenario wherein to take course `0`, I have to take multiple prerequisite courses, say, `1` and `2`?  Using the latter representation, I would end up completing course `0` from `1` (thanks to the edge), without first doing course `2`.

How should I create the directional edge?

Comment: Note that I have a similar question for [this one](https://leetcode.com/problems/course-schedule-iv/) as well.

Comment: Do you want an edge to represent an action you *shall* take, or an action you *might* take? That is, if the only requirement is that you take 1 and 2 before 0, then do you want a graph like `{1->2, 2->0}` or a graph like `{1->2, 2->1, 1->0, 2->0}`?

Comment: It is possible to finish all courses if and only if the graph has no cycles. Seen this way, it doesn't matter which way the edges point.

Comment: @Beta, I don't really know.  The only requirement is that courses `1` and `2` should be completed before course `0`.  How we model the graph is up to us.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Which part is unclear?

Comment: If you don't know what you want to accomplish with the tool, we can't advise you how to use it.

Comment: @Beta, that misses the point.  I am asking how to assemble the tool first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter. If you reverse all your edges and topological sort, the result that you'll get will be the reverse of some topological ordering of the original graph. Do it in whichever way makes the most sense to you.